# LibreOffice Calc - UDF in c# dotnet

Tags: .net, user-defined-functions, libreoffice-calc

In MS Excel, it is possible to create User-defined functions in C#.
Is there a way to do this also in LibreOffice Calc?

I have been looking for some information about this but I only found some documentation to do this in Python or BASIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when people use C# with UNO (and it's not done very often), they write a C# application that connects to LibreOffice and sends commands. A UDF, on the other hand, would be the opposite — it would need to be initiated from within LibreOffice.

That means you're probably limited to the languages that LibreOffice can run from inside. According to https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Extension_Development:

> Supported programming languages are Basic, Python, JavaScript, Java, BeanShell and C++.

With any of those languages, you could set up a bridge from a Basic UDF, or you could create a Calc add-in.

I can think of an alternative, which is to use a system call from a Basic UDF to call your C# program. It sounds like a mess though.

Personally, even if it were possible to cobble together a UDF with the main work done in C#, I would not do it, because that's not the preferred language for this kind of task. Why not take the time to learn a new language instead, for example, Java (similar to C#) or Python (popular with UNO nowadays)? If you are a professional programmer, learning a new language should not be something to shy away from.

Comment: Thanks for the info and advice. Doing in another language is an option but at this moment we are working on a migration to a C# environment. I hoped to do this in different steps and with reusable code.